# What do we call a gait in which a person drags his feet?

Tags: word-request

What do we call a gait in which a person drags his feet?

Something like *wobble* or *stagger*. The person in question walks straight; its just that he's too lazy or tired to lift his feet.

Answer (score 3):

1. A **shambling** gait, from the verb *to [shamble](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/shamble)*.
2. A **shuffling** gait, from the verb *to [shuffle](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/shuffle)*.

An [example](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_%22Bab%22_Ballads/Joe_Golightly) of use:

> A "tar", but poorly prized,
>    Long, **shambling**, and unsightly,
>   Thrashed, bullied, and despised,
>   Was wretched Joe Golightly.

Another, from "[Aaron Stark](http://www.theotherpages.org/poems/robin03.html)" by E.A. Robinson:

> Glad for the murmur of his hard renown,
>   Year after year he **shambled** through the town, --
>   A loveless exile moving with a staff;
>   And oftentimes there crept into his ears
>   A sound of alien pity, touched with tears, --
>   And then (and only then) did Aaron laugh.

Answer (score 1):

I would call it a *shuffling gait*.  It could be due to laziness or tiredness. It could also signify a [medical problem](http://symptomchecker.webmd.com/single-symptom?symptom=shuffling-gait-%28feet%29&symid=509).  It is also a technique used by [ultramarathoners](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cliff_Young_(athlete)#The_Young_Shuffle).

Comment: Sorry, but I have to disagree. Maybe it's a BrE perspective, but to me a person *shuffling **his feet*** is an idiomatic usage. He's either sitting or standing *in one place* (not making any forward progress). Usually context makes it clear he's indicating embarrassment, indecision, impatience, or whatever.

Comment: While it's true that one can _shuffle their feet_ while sitting in a chair, we can still use _shuffle_ to answer this question. (Shoppers might [_shuffle through the mall_](https://www.google.com/search?safe=off&q="shuffled+through+the+mall"), for example.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there would be a distinction between tired & lazy.

Using examples already mentioned…
shambling or shuffling gait might signify tiredness rather than laziness.

weary gait would definitely imply not making the greatest effort to stride out like a soldier on parade.

Though grammatically it might not be the best - idle, lazy or even indolent [of an irritated & irritable adolescent] gait would convey the right meaning; or you could just say they were dragging their feet.

Consider the typical Japanese teenager in his/her 250 buck trainers/sneakers… dragging their feet & breaking the shoes down at the backs is fashionable, not lazy. The result, to anyone over 40 looks risible, but so was rock'n'roll to a 1950's parent.

Straight from the thesaurus, you could use lumber, totter, dodder, stumble; scuff one's feet; hobble, limp.

Answer (score -1):

I have never encountered "shuffling" to be equivalent to "dragging". Shuffling gait can be used more medically. Dragging would be more akin to staggering, as in for drunkards. I do not know what the term is for the walkers who cannot seem to pick up their feet ... which creates dragging sounds from their shoes, but definitely those sound depressed or if daily, the impression of laziness. Could they just pick up their feet when walking?

Comment: I just wanted to clarify. Are you asking a question or are you trying to answer the OP? If you are trying to address one (or more) of the answers, that's not really the correct usage of the Answers section. You can use a comment for that, but you will [gain that privilege](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) on this site when you reach 50 reputation.